# RancherOS + K8s On Single Physical Machine with Multiple Nodes

Tags: devops, rancher

So I installed RancherOS after that Rancher and got My Kubernetes Cluster.

Added singled node with all roles,

now thinking how to add more nodes on the same physical machine. Any advices what docker image u used to run rancher agent on it, so I can spin another node for k8s cluster?
I just want to run multiple nodes on a single physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try k3s (this is a product from the rancher labs).
You can run the kubernetes cluster on one machine via docker-compose